# CDI-Unsatisfied dependencies for type QueueSession

Tags: annotations, jms, cdi

I am trying to write annotations to inject JMS resources. Here is my code

```
public class JMSResourceProducer {

    private static final String WL_INIT_CONN_FACTORY ="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    private String WL_SERVER_URL = "URL";
    private String QF ="QFNAME";
    private String QQ ="QNAME";

    public InitialContext createInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, WL_INIT_CONN_FACTORY);
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WL_SERVER_URL);
        return new InitialContext(properties);
    }

    @Produces @Image2000
    public QueueSession createQueueSession () throws NamingException, JMSException {
        InitialContext initialContext = createInitialContext();
        QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(QF);
        QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        return queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, 0);
    }

    @Produces @Image2000
    public Queue createQueue ( ) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext initialContext = createInitialContext();
        Queue queue = (Queue)initialContext.lookup(QQ);
        return queue;
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it in my class

```
@Inject @Image2000
    private QueueSession queueSession;

    @Inject @Image2000
    private Queue jmsQueue;
```

My annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Image2000 {
}
```

But I am getting below error when my Wildfly starts..

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type QueueSession with qualifiers @Image2000
```

at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Image2000 .queueSession

Any clue whats wrong with my producer class ?

Comment: Could you provide the complete logs when the Weld container bootstraps in `DEBUG` level for the `org.jboss.weld` logger?

Comment: JMSResourceProducer, does not seem to be a bean. Annotate it with '@Stateless' or '@ApplicationScope'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the discovery mode defined in beans.xml, you may need to annotate JMSResourceProducer with a bean defining annotation (Dependent, ApplicationScoped or another better suited).

Comment: Adding @Dependent on the class resolved my problem. Thanks jpangamarca